# ActiveRecord object created with null values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, activerecord

I am trying to create a 'visit' object from json sent by AJAX. Here's the model:

```
class Visit < ApplicationRecord
    serialize :number, JSON
    serialize :time_spent, JSON
end
```

and here's the migration file:

```
class CreateVisits < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    def change
      create_table :visits do |t|
          t.integer :number
          t.integer :time_spent

          t.timestamps
      end
    end
 end
```

I have an action called show, which contains the following script:

```
var start;
$(document).ready(function() {
    start = Date.getTime();
    $(window).unload(function() {
        end = Date.getTime;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/log",
            data: { visit: { 'number': <% @number %>,'time_spent': end - start} }
        })
    });
}
```

to measure the time spent on the page. The route for '/log' is:

```
get '/log', to: 'home_page#log', :defaults => { format: 'json' }
```

and home_page#log is:

```
def log
   @visit = Visit.new(visit_params)
   respond_to do |format|
       if @visit.save
          format.json { render json: @visit.to_json }
       end
   end
end
```

where visit_params is:

```
private
def visit_params
    params.require(:visit).permit(:number, :time_spent)
end
```

When I navigate to /log, I receive an error saying that the visit param is missing or empty.

EDIT:

I fixed the error in the route so that it is now post instead of get. However, no message of a visit being saved is logged in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

seems that the route should be post and not get:

```
post '/log', to: 'home_page#log', :defaults => { format: 'json' }
```

Comment: I did this, but no visit objects were saved

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JS is valid. What's the output of your params going into your controller? Also be sure to include the '=' in your ERB: `<%= @number %>`

Try:

```
var start;
var end;
$(document).ready(function() {
 start = new Date().getTime();
 $(window).unload(function() {
    end = new Date().getTime();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: "/log",
      data: { visit: { 'number': <%= @number %>,'time_spent': end - start} }
    })
 });
}
```

Also in your migration, you should be saving it as text rather than an integer.